# Почему не меняется БД?

Tags: php, база-данных, mysql

```
$link=@mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_password,$db_databases);
$sql="CREATE DATABASE world";
/* проверяем соединение */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* возвращаем имя текущей базы данных */
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT DATABASE()")) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    printf("Default database is %s.\n", $row[0]);
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

/* изменяем текущую базу данных на world */
mysqli_select_db($link, "world");

/* возвращаем имя текущей базы данных */
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT DATABASE()")) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    printf("Default database is %s.\n", $row[0]);
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

Почему не меняется БД? Два раза выводится текущая БД.

Comment: кхм, а вы выполнили запрос $sql на создание базы?

Comment: Переключится только на существующую БД. А я вижу, что запросик вы написали:

    $sql="CREATE DATABASE world";

Но где эта база создаётся - не вижу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проверьте, что возвращает эта строка:

```
mysqli_select_db($link, "world");
```

Если `FALSE` - значит, какая-то ошибка. Может, такая база отсутствует, или у юзера под которым коннектитесь, нет к ней прав доступа.